# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected issue

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
    maint_id,
    to_char(maint_datetime, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') AS date,
    prop_address,
    owner_givname
    || ' '
    || owner_famname AS owner_name,
    maint_desc,
    maint_cost
FROM 
    rent.maintenance
    NATURAL JOIN rent.property
    NATURAL JOIN rent.owner
WHERE
        maint_cost > 1000
    AND maint_cost < 3000
ORDER BY
    maint_cost DESC,
    maint_datetime;
```

I don't undersatnd why I still keep gatting the ORA-00923 error, could someone help to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is about the column alias; you used `date` which is a keyword, reserved for the `date` datatype.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') date
  2  from dual;
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') date
                                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Modify it to something else, or (if you must) enclose it into double quotes:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') datum,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') "date"
  3  from dual;

DATUM      date
---------- ----------
09-05-2023 09-05-2023

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html) and you cannot use it as an (unquoted) identifier.

Either use a different identifier `maint_date` or use a quoted identifier `"date"`.

```sql
SELECT
    maint_id,
    to_char(maint_datetime, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') AS maint_date,
    prop_address,
    owner_givname
    || ' '
    || owner_famname AS owner_name,
    maint_desc,
    maint_cost
FROM 
    rent.maintenance
    NATURAL JOIN rent.property
    NATURAL JOIN rent.owner
WHERE
        maint_cost > 1000
    AND maint_cost < 3000
ORDER BY
    maint_cost DESC,
    maint_datetime;
```